# R call variable inside sqldf

Tags: r, loops, variables, sqldf

I need to do a loop over sqldf statements and for that I need to call the loop variable inside the sqldf code:

My table "data", might be:

```
data <- read.table(text ="
    loaddate DaysRange DaysRangeNext
1 2014-03-16        30            30
2 2014-03-16         0             0
3 2014-03-16         0             0
4 2014-03-16        60            NA
5 2014-04-16        30            30
6 2014-04-16         0            30
"
,header = TRUE)
```

then  I format loaddate as a date:

```
data$loaddate<-as.Date(as.character(data$loaddate), format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Let's say I have a vector "loaddates":

```
loaddates<- unique(sort(data$loaddate))
```

And I need to run the following code for each loaddate:

```
for (i in loaddates) {

sqldf("
SELECT D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext, 
COUNT(*) AS clientes
FROM data AS D
WHERE D.loaddate = i
GROUP BY D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
ORDER BY D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
")        }
```

But I get the followng error:

> Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) :    error in
>   statement: no such column: i

Is there a way to keep the variable value and use it inside the loop?

Thanks.

EDITION:

I tried:

```
sqldf(
strwrap(sprintf("
SELECT D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext, 
COUNT(*) AS clientes 
FROM data AS D
WHERE D.LoadDate = '%s'
GROUP BY D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
ORDER BY D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
",i),simplify=TRUE,width=1000000))
```

But I got:

> ```
> > [1] loaddate      DaysRange     DaysRangeNext clientes      <0 rows>
> > (or 0-length row.names)
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `i` will not be replaced in the query as it is. You need `sprintf` to assign a value to it. (I also don't know if you need to account for break lines but just to be sure I provide it below. Maybe you don't need for sqldf; in which case just remove strwrap).

```
#let's assume loaddates is the following:
loaddates <- 'something'
```

One way to get the query as you want, i.e. with no break lines and with `i` taking the values of loaddates you need:

```
strwrap(sprintf("
                SELECT D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext, 
                COUNT(*) AS clientes
                FROM deuda AS D
                WHERE D.loaddate = '%s'
                GROUP BY D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
                ORDER BY D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
                ",i),simplify=TRUE,width=1000000)
```

which will output:

```
[1] "SELECT D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext, COUNT(*) AS clientes FROM deuda AS D WHERE D.CodEmp = 'TGG' and D.loaddate = something GROUP BY D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext ORDER BY D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext"
```

Which is what you need in one line with no break lines or with the variable `i` unassigned.

In your loop it should be:

```
for (i in loaddates) {

strwrap(sprintf("
                SELECT D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext, 
                COUNT(*) AS clientes
                FROM deuda AS D
                WHERE D.loaddate = '%s'
                GROUP BY D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
                ORDER BY D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
                ",i),simplify=TRUE,width=1000000)

}
```

With your dataset:

```
library(sqldf)
data <- read.table(text ="
    loaddate DaysRange DaysRangeNext
1 2014-03-16        30            30
2 2014-03-16         0             0
3 2014-03-16         0             0
4 2014-03-16        60            NA
5 2014-04-16        30            30
6 2014-04-16         0            30
"
                   ,header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=F)

loaddates<- unique(sort(data$loaddate))

for (i in loaddates) {

  print(sqldf(
  strwrap(sprintf("
                SELECT D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext, 
                COUNT(*) AS clientes
                FROM data AS D
                WHERE D.loaddate = '%s'
                GROUP BY D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
                ORDER BY D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
                ",i),simplify=TRUE,width=1000000) ))
}
```

Output:

```
    loaddate DaysRange DaysRangeNext clientes
1 2014-03-16         0             0        2
2 2014-03-16        30            30        1
3 2014-03-16        60            NA        1
    loaddate DaysRange DaysRangeNext clientes
1 2014-04-16         0            30        1
2 2014-04-16        30            30        1
```

Comment: It needed quotes around `%s`. Try it now. I updated it.

Comment: same result with quotes

Comment: but mine works I just ran it! copy paste my example and check. You need `print` in there to see it. You also didn't add a column in your dataset `CodEmp`

Comment: btw `loaddate` column in data is of type `character` the way I use it. Is yours `Date` type?

Comment: Print was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: :) Happy to have helped (although it took me a few tries) !!

Comment: I think the issue is that the date must be casted as a string. If you keep it as a Date the code does not work (or you should format your date in the `sprintf`)

Comment: @Barranka Thanks for the comment. It seems to be working with the way you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You might get this working by defining your SQL statement within the loop but outside the function call.

```
for (i in loaddates) {

statement = paste( " SELECT D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext,
              COUNT(*) AS clientes
              FROM data AS D
              WHERE D.loaddate = ", i,
"GROUP BY D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
ORDER BY D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext " )

sqldf(statement)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a new data frame. Then join to it:

```
num_Pcode <- as.numeric("3550")
df_Pcode_0 <- as.data.frame(num_Pcode)
df_Pcode_0
...
```

returns `num_Pcode`.

Answer (score 0):

`fn$sqldf` allows the use of `$` within the sql statement to interpolate R variables.  See Example 5 on the sqldf github home page and see the bottom of the help page `?fn` for many more examples.  We could reduce `setNames(loaddates, loaddates)` to just `loaddates` if we don't need names on the output.

```
Map(function(i)
  fn$sqldf("
    SELECT D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext, 
    COUNT(*) AS clientes
    FROM data AS D
    WHERE D.loaddate = $i
    GROUP BY D.LoadDate,D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
    ORDER BY D.DaysRange, D.DaysRangeNext
  "), setNames(loaddates, loaddates))
```

giving:

```
$`2014-03-16`
    loaddate DaysRange DaysRangeNext clientes
1 2014-03-16         0             0        2
2 2014-03-16        30            30        1
3 2014-03-16        60            NA        1

$`2014-04-16`
    loaddate DaysRange DaysRangeNext clientes
1 2014-04-16         0            30        1
2 2014-04-16        30            30        1
```